# Schengen visa requirement for newly-married wife of a British citizen with a family member residence card through her son-in-law?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, uk-residents, cameroonian-citizens

As above, I'm getting married on 1st Aug as a UK national. My wife is non-EU (Cameroonian) but has a residency card for the UK through her son-in-law who is Polish but resident in the UK.

Does she need a visa to visit another EU country for our honeymoon, i.e. Spain or Greece?

Comment: her residency card is for UK where she is living now with her daughter and son-in-law

Comment: This question is actually a expatriates.stackexchange.com question. An extra question would be: will the residence card of **dependent** of an EU Citizen living in another EU country remain valid after a marriage to a non EU Citizen. Any answer would also be conditional to when any visit takes place (during 2020 or after).

Comment: I would simplify. While she still holds the document card, it will be accepted at the border. Indeed, if she divorced in Poland the permit should have been withdrawn. Immigration officers check for documents **at the travel date**, so maybe the OP will have to consider changes in her status after marriage.

Comment: @Philip Johnstone The terminology you’re using is confusing. The UK is not part of Schengen. Please clarify eg does your wife hold an Article 10 or 20 Residence Card or a UK-issued EEA family permit? https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card

Comment: If she is no longer a resident of Poland, the polish residence permit becomes invalid. The question states that the polish citizen lives in the UK,  therefore she must have permit as **dependent** of a EU Citizen living the UK. The UK was never a Schengen country, thus the wrong terminology was used by the OP. With an Article 10 card issued in the non Schengen country, when not travelling with the polish brother inlaw, she will need a visa. She is no longer dependent on the polish son inlaw since her marriage. If not noted on the card it may still work when traveling with the UK husband.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ Where does the OP mention divorce in Poland?

Comment: @Traveller The wife will probably require a new permit reflecting her new status as a spouse of a UK Citizen.

Comment: @Mark Johnson Agreed, however I’m not aware of any route to apply for one in anticipation of the marriage. So, assuming the honeymoon will directly follow the marriage (as is normal practice, and as the OP’s question implies), the question is: can she travel with her existing permit. It’s therefore worth clarifying exactly which permit she holds, IMHO

Comment: @Traveller Applying vor a C-Visa as an EU-Citizen dependent (free and speedy) would resolve the matter.

Comment: Because there is no such thing as "a schengen residency card for the UK" I have voted to close this question as needing clarity or additional details.  Please edit the question to clarify precisely what document she has.  Then I will retract my vote or vote to reopen.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question because, as several people commented, some of the terminology was very confusing. I assumed (1) you're a British citizen (2) your (future) wife has a residence card for the UK as a member of her dependent son's family (i.e. an EU family member residence card and not a “Schengen“ anything), unrelated to her relationship with you. Please let us know if any of this is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, citizens of Cameroon generally need a C-Visa to enter the Schengen Area for a short term visit.

**Assumptions**:

Your future wife is a family member (Mother in law) of a EU Citizen (polish) residing in the United Kingdom (which is **not** a Schengen Member state) .

- has an Article 10 or 20 Residence Card as a **dependent** family member
- the EU Citizen, against which the residence card was issued, will **not** be traveling with her

When a family member is **not** travelling with or joining the EU Citizen, a C-Visa (Schengen Visa) is required. Such visas are generally issued under special conditions

- free of charge (3.4.2 Visa Code Handbook)
- an appointment is often not required and issued swiftly
- multiple entries and valid for a longer period

Such an application must be made at the Consulate of your **primary** destination for the first visit (i.e. where you will be staying the longest or, in tie situations, the first).

You should check if your future spouse allready has such a visa and that it has not expired.

With such a visa, the 90/180 rule applies.

In theory, once you have married, she will become a spouse of an UK Citizen who, until the 31st of December 2020, will be treated as a EU Citizen within the Schengen Area. When traveling **together** your spouse would not need a visa during 2020.

So taking a verified copy of your **marriage certificate** with you should cover you both ways, insuring that any pedantic technocrat will find no fault, since a new United Kingdom residence permit will unlikely be issued in time for your honeymoon.

One would hope that a certain **grace** time exists for such situations, but I know of none.

Comment: Why wouldn't she need a visa if travelling with her British citizen husband? Why would the visa be free of charge if she isn't?

Comment: To clarify: what matters to the visa exemption is holding the appropriate residence card, not merely being the spouse of an EU citizen (there are some caveats but the visa requirement does in principle apply).

Comment: @Relaxed It's clearly stated within the answer. a) Travelling with her spouse, who will be treated as a EU Citizen during 2020 no visa is required. b) When traveling alone an Article 10/20 Residence card holder will be issued a visa free of charge. (3.4.2 Visa Code Handbook)

Comment: @Relaxed The condition on which it was issued will change apon marriage. The card was issued as a dependent of the son inlaw. Traveling with him no visa is required.

Comment: I share your interpretation of the facts but I am still surprised by the conclusions you draw from these facts. Could you cite a specific legal basis for your contentions? I would prefer a reference to the actual regulations but if you must quote a Handbook then with a link/date and a page number because it has changed quite a bit. The [last version I found](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/20140709_visa_code_handbook_consolidated_en.pdf) doesn't have a section 3.4.2 and in fact contradicts what you wrote (p. 102).

Comment: For the record: I do agree with this comment *The condition on which it was issued will change apon marriage. The card was issued as a dependent of the son inlaw. Traveling with him no visa is required.* but your answer doesn't reflect it.

Comment: Visa Code Handbook 14.5.2019  ; 28.1.2020 page 36 (both 3.4.2, page 37 of pdf reader) Mandatory fee waivers or fee reductions applicable to all applicants or certain categories of applicants: 0 EUR Family members of EU citizens covered by Directive 2004/38/EC and of Swiss citizens,

Comment: Freedom of movement Article 5(4) Right of entry: Where a Union citizen, or a family member who is not a national of a Member State, **does not have the necessary travel documents or, if required, the necessary visas, the Member State concerned shall**, before turning them back, give such persons every reasonable opportunity to obtain the necessary documents or have them brought to them within a reasonable period of time or **to corroborate or prove by other means that they are covered by the right of free movement** and residence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110983/discussion-between-relaxed-and-mark-johnson).

Comment: I just came across https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154802/can-i-travel-to-any-schengen-country-with-my-euss-family-permit-issued-by-the-uk after it was bumped to the homepage and I noticed phoog already corrected the same mistake back in March. Will this become one of the falsehoods you keep repeating while dropping the discussion every time you're proven wrong?